# How to replace a laptop's battery without shutting down?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, shutdown, charging

- Background information: I take my laptop to three classes in one day every week where I don't have access to a power socket to charge my laptop, but I have an extra laptop battery fully charged in my backpack. Also, my laptop is Thinkpad T510 Windows 10.
- Question: Is there any way to replace my almost dying laptop's battery with my fully charged one without facing any shutdown? (Assume ***no*** power socket and power cord is available to use).

Answer (score 1):

You could fabricate a power source based on a "power bank" to feed power in via the normal charging port but that would mean more things to carry.

It may be easier to do a shutdown saving all the docs etc and just change the batteries over.

Comment: I see yeah a power bank might not be a bad idea, that's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had a power socket available, according to [this discussion](https://superuser.com/q/131727/328618) it seems not clear if all models support hot plugging.

Without any clever hardware addition, which would provide interim power, I believe using hibernate mode (not sleep mode) is the way to go, it is supposed to persist all state on your drive. See [here #3](https://www.michaellinenberger.com/blog/four-windows-10-power-settings-you-should-probably-change-hibernation-and-sleep/) how to add it to your power menu.

Comment: Cool, I will give that a try soon. If that works for me, its a game changer. Thanks.